# Read csv and add image in category Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, image

I tried this code but i could not upload image

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');

ini_set('max_execution_time', 36000);
ini_set('post_max_size', '5000M');
ini_set("memory_limit","4046M");
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5000M');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$obj->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');
$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

function readCSV($csvFile)
{
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
    {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 2024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

$csvFile = 'upload.csv';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre/>';
for($i=1;$i < (count($csv)-1);$i++)
{
    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('*'))
                ->addFieldToFilter('name',array('eq' => $csv[$i][0]));
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    $categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
    $categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');

    $value =(array)$category->getData('entity_id');
    $category1 = $categoryFactory->create()->load($value[0]['entity_id']);

    $imagePath=$csv[$i][1];
    $mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');

    $category1->setImage($imagePath, $mediaAttribute, true, false);                 
    $category1->save();
}
```

I can get image path from csv but i could not upload that
**CSV File Formate**
[image]

Comment: Why you dont't use the Import function from the Mag2 System->Import ?

Comment: @Marcel We did not find import option for category

Comment: Yes sorry i missunderstood. How many images you have to upload. It is nessesary to upload via script?